# how to push my footer down to bottom of page?

Tags: html, css

aim: to have my footer pushed to bottom of the webpage. not a sticky footer but once scrolled passed content it is at bottom. for example on my laptop it appears at bottom but on a big monitor its not stuck to bottom only just below content. i.e [image: what it is on my laptop]
But on a big monitor: [image: on a big screen]

the css code of the footer:

```
    text-align: center !important;
    padding: 3px;
    z-index: 1000000;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 20px;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
    margin-left: -10;
    position: relative;
    width: 103%;
    margin-bottom: -10px !important;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-height: 400px;
} 
body{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

if you need anything else jsut ask

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+footer+bottom+site:stackoverflow.com&)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: try this footer {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
}